# Converting object to string JQuery/JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a list of countries to my select tag, but whatever I try it keeps showing as [object Object]. Here is my JS code:

I've tried var x = JSON.Stringify(country); and passing that into var o, and I've also tried country.toLocaleString('en-US); and that has not worked either. How can I have the countries show in the select list? Thanks

Comment: can you add op of  `report.regions.world.list` in your question?

Comment: Here is the report: https://cov19.cc/report.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `world_list[i].country` to access country.

Here is demo code :

```js
//your json
var report={"last_updated":"2020-06-02T04:15:21Z","regions":{"world":{"name":"World","totals":{"confirmed":6370499,"recovered":2904076,"deaths":377515,"critical":2811064,"tests":11709},"list":[{"country":"Hong Kong","confirmed":1088,"deaths":4,"recovered":1037,"Incidence_Rate":"14.49915619446103","Case-Fatality_Ratio":"0.36798528058877644","last_updated":"2020-06-02T04:15:21Z","country_code":"hk","daily_confirmed":0,"daily_deaths":0,"critical":47,"tests":5},{"country":"Macao","confirmed":45,"deaths":-1,"recovered":45,"Incidence_Rate":"6.930092308829553","Case-Fatality_Ratio":"0.0","last_updated":"2020-06-02T04:15:21Z","country_code":"mo","daily_confirmed":0,"daily_deaths":-1,"critical":0,"tests":-1}]}}};

var world_list = report.regions.world.list;

    for(var i in world_list){
      //use word_list[i].country  to retrieve slected value
      var o = new Option(world_list[i].country, i);
      $("select").append(o);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
</select>
```